# To Get YEARMONTH from date in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, yearmonth

I can get year and month separately in Athena but i don't know how to get YEARMONTH from date.

```
select year(date1) from table1
select Month(date1) from table1
```

Please suggest how to get YEARMONTH. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) to represent your date in needed format:

```sql
select date_format(now(), '%Y%m')
```

Comment: How to use same query in DBeaver 7.1.2 version and in VANDYKE -EMR - SecureCRT? SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FIELD1,'%y%m' from table1 ?

Comment: @Dee not sure I fully understand your question. Have never used second one and in first one - as any other SQL query.

Comment: i have multiple tools in company to get data and all are 3 different tools which i havent used it before.....so i need to keep writing queries in all 3 tools, and same query doesnt work in another tool. so just wondering if you are aware query for DBeaver tool and EMR tool to get YEARMONTH.....

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I got the query for Dbeaver. select concat(date_part(year,field1), date_part(month, field1)) from table1. let me know if there are any better way to write this one.....